# Why does a balance try to be horizontal? The moments are equal

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque

Suppose we have an ordinary balance where equal weights are put in both sides. Now one side is slowly held down. When this force is not applied anymore, the balance tends to achieve horizontal position.

But when one side is held down, the moment of force due to both weights are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction. Also, the potential energy of the system remains same (As the height lost by one weight is equal to the height gained by another). So why does the balance try to regain horizontal position?

[image]

Here $r$, $F (=mg)$ and $\sin \theta$ are equal

Comment: Why do you say that "But when one side is held down, the moment of force due to both weights are equal in magnitude and $\mathbb{opposite \,\ in \,\ direction}$."? Can you please explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13474/

Comment: @Gert I could not find this question previously. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13474/ So should I delete this question?

Comment: @Aniket Torque = rxF. Here r, F and θ are equal in case of both the weights. If we apply right had rule, the directions will be opposite

Comment: What about the moment of the arm itself?