# Why a mechanical balance can balance?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, equilibrium, stability

[image]

In the above diagram, assume that the level is solid and massless:

- In the left setup, both mass are fixed on the level.  As we know, it is not a stable mechanical balance. For any tilt, the level will tilt more.
- In the right setup, both mass are hanged from a fixed location from the level. It is also the normal and old-fashioned setup for mechanical analytic balance.  As we know, it is a stable mechanical balance.  If one end is heavier than the other, the level will tilt to an angle and restore the balance.

But I can arrive at the above conclusion using mechanical analysis, e.g.:

1. If the two ends are not balanced, at what angle the level will stop.
2. For the above to happen, what is the range of the ability to restore balance at any tilted angle.

Thank you.

Comment: Question 2 is ambiguous.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: There's so much wrong with this question I wouldn't know where to start. So I won't.

Comment: What is not clear? If two ends are not balanced slightly, will the mechanical balance be balanced again at a tilted angle? If so, what is the threshold for this to happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the weighing balance restore when tilted and released](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13474/why-does-the-weighing-balance-restore-when-tilted-and-released)

Comment: Yes, "Why does the weighing balance restore when tilted and released" is the answer,. Thanks!